# Generating stored procedures for insert,update and delete automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I generate insert and update stored procedures for specific or all tables automatically in SQL Server ?

Is it possible ? thanks in advance

Comment: Add more information please. What do the stored procedures need to do? Why do you want stored procedures if you only do insert and update? Yes it is possible, but give us more information

Comment: Any halfway decent code generator can do this - check out MyGeneration or CodeSmith (you'll find them on Google or Bing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tons of tools that can do this for you, some free, some that you pay for. Here is a simple one with source you can adapt:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19280/Stored-Procedure-Generator

and here is an SSMS addin, that is also free (or for a small fee depending on the version you choose).

http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Answer (score -2):

```
-- It is for std table
create proc std_delete
@id int
as begin
delete from std  where id=@id
end

execute  std_delete  2
-- SP for delete

--Now u can c
select * from std
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question as such